# What does this error mean when using .searchable()?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios17, xcode15

I am getting the following error when trying to use the `.searchable()` modifier in a SwiftUI application:

```
Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.
If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Here is the code that replicates the error for me:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
                .navigationTitle("Searchable Example")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}
```

Seems like a simple use of the modifier and I can't imagine this is a problem on my side.  Is it just log noise to be ignored?  If so is there some way to suppress these warnings? Or am I using the modifier incorrectly somehow?

Answer (score -1):

The `.searchable` modifier must be **inside** the scope of the `NavigationStack`,
in your case on the same level as `.navigationTitle`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
                .navigationTitle("Searchable Example")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error even if the modifier is inside the NavitaionStack.  It does't appear right away ... but if you keep editing for several keystrokes it will manifest the same error again and again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error inside the navigation stack.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you ... I use exactly the code you provided and I get the errors immediately when running in the emulator.